# Python inheritance

Tags: python, class, inheritance, methods

My base code looks like this:

```
class C1(object):
    def f(self):
    return 2*self.g()

    def g(self):
    return 2

class C2(C1):
    def f(self):
    return 3*self.g()


class C3(C1):
    def g(self):
        return 5

class C4(C3):
    def f(self):
    return 7*self.g()

obj1 = C1()
obj2 = C2()
obj3 = C3()
obj4 = C4()
```

Now my question is the following: I need to write three assignment statements that do the following:

- assign the **calling list** for `obj2.f()` to the variable `obj2_calls`
- assign the **calling list** for `obj3.f()` to the variable `obj3_calls`
- assign the **calling list** for `obj4.f()` to the variable `obj4_calls`

Calling list being for example, when `obj1.f()` is called, the `f` method of `C1` is called which calls the `g` method of `C1`. This could be represented as a **calling list** of the form `['C1.f', 'C1.g']`

I don't quite know the proper way to write the assignment statements and I desperately want to help out my friend with her stuff.

If you could just show me how to properly right out the first assignment statement, I'm sure I could figure out the rest.

Comment: FYI, homework is fine on Stack Overflow. Homework *with no effort shown* is the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key insight is that if a method is not defined for a class, it will default to use the method of a class that the class inherits.

Thus, ask yourself what 'obj2.f()' will do.

- **What class is `obj2`?** It is `C2`.
- **Is there an `f` method defined for class `C2`?** Yes, there is. So the method `C2.f` is called.
- The `C2.f` method calls `self.g`, which means it looks for `C2.g`. **Is there a 'C2.g' method?** No, so we have to go to the class that `C2` inherits from. The line `class C2(C1)` tells us that it is inherited from the class `C1`, so it will call the method `C1.g`.

Those are the steps to get the first calling list; the rest are up to you.